How can i cancel an export in Azure using az cli?
I have a snapshot and i want to run "Cancel Export" using az cli instead of clicking in Azure.
How can i do this using az cli cmdlets ?

I created one VM snapshot and enabled its export that created SAS URL with Cancel Export button as below:

To cancel the export of snapshot using Azure CLI, you can make use of below command:
az snapshot revoke-access --name <snapshot_name> --resource-group <rg_name>

Response:

When I checked the same in Portal by refreshing the page, snapshot export cancelled successfully and displayed this page:

Reference:
az snapshot | Microsoft
